# How to add JsonDeserializer to Kafka consumer in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin, apache-kafka

How can i add `JsonDeserializer` to my Kafka consumer. I'm receiving now a Json string and want to convert it into a data class object.

This is my consumer :

ConsumerConfig :

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {
@Value("\${kafka.host:localhost}")
private val host: String? = null

@Value("\${kafka.port:9092}")
private val port: Int = 0

@Bean
fun userConsumerConfigs(): ConsumerFactory<String, String> {
    val props = HashMap<String, Any>()
    props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "$host:$port"
    props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
    props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
    props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "helloworld"
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props, StringDeserializer(), StringDeserializer())

    //return props
}


@Bean
fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(): 
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, 
String>> {
    val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
    factory.consumerFactory = userConsumerConfigs()
    return factory
}

@Bean
fun kafkaConsumer(): Consumerz {
    return Consumerz()
}

companion object {
    const val TOPIC = "test"
}
}
```

Consumer :

```
class Consumerz {
@KafkaListener(topics = ["usertest"])
fun receive(message: String) {
     LOGGER.info("Received payload= $message")

}

companion object {
    private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumerz::class.java)
}
}
```

I'm using at the moment only `StringDeserializer`. How could i implement `JsonDeserializer` in this case.

Current output is : `Received payload= { "firstName": "Jack", "lastName" : "Adam" }`

Thanks in advance.

@ this is a **Spring** project .

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.class` as below

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

So, the consumer configuration will be :

```
private ConsumerFactory<String, MyDomainModel> myMessageFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "KAPP");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MyDomainModel.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyDomainModel> myMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyDomainModel> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(myMessageFactory());
    return factory;
}
```